# Как исправить ошибку с загрузкой картинки в wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Когда я пытаюсь поставить иконку в верхней панели сайта, мне пишет "При обрезке изображения произошла ошибка"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Я нашел ответ.
Заходите в паку где у вас установлен опен сервер (С:\xampp), у меня например XAMPP. Захожу на него и открываю папку php (С:\xampp\php), и в нем открываю файл php.ini через любой редактор. Там ищите строчку ";extension=gd" и убираете точку с запятой ";"

Comment: Вот список расширений php, которые нужны для WordPress: https://make.wordpress.org/hosting/handbook/server-environment/

Comment: Если бы вы изучили, что нужно для работы WordPress,  вопроса бы не возникло.

Comment: Это пример дурацкого, если не вредного ответа. Во первых ни про какие опенсерверы речи в вопросе не было, во вторых это касается настроек сервера, а не ВП. Ну и в третьих нужен не GD, а imagik.